# Laravel & Artisan giving french errors

Tags: php, sql, laravel

For some reason, while running this code:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=CitiesTableSeeder
```

Give me this code, half of it in French:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table 'ersh.cities'
n'existe pas
```

I am not sure how to correct this. I know there is another problem here, but I don't want to mix questions. Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming it's MySQL.  If not, please state which language and I'll try to find the correct command.

The language for lc_message is set to French for the DBMS.

To change to US English run:

```
mysqld --lc_messages_dir=/usr/share/mysql --lc_messages=en_US
```

### EDIT

WAMP is built by French developers, so look in the `my.ini` file for

```
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

and change it to

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am running this on Windows 7. Is there a way to set this permanently in my.ini or somewhere else?