# Foreign Key on Laravel Migration causing General Error 1215

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to create multiple tables with foreign keys using Laravels migration. I have a problems migration table like so

```
Schema::create('problems', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('category')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

A categories migration

```
Schema::create('categories', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('category_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My first foreign key into the users migration works fine but as soon as it hits the foreign key for the category id, it gives a

> SQLSTATE HY000 General Error 1215 Impossible d'ajouter des contraintes
>   d'index externe (SQL; alter table 'problems' add constraint
>   problems_category_foreign foreign key ('category') references
>   'categories' ('id'))

(I can't properly read the French and I don't know why it gives me errors in French. I have not been able to find a way to change it as I am not French, nor can I understand it)

I don't understand why this would work for one and not the other when they are essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the order of the migration files work out. For example, you cannot create a problems table with a foreign key that references `id` on categories table before you actually create the categories table itself.

For the french error problem, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654646/laravel-artisan-giving-french-errors).

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the migrations order

```
|-database/
|--migrations/
|---2015_02_02_141725_create_problems_table.php
|---2015_03_01_234626_create_categories_table.php
```

Should be:

```
|-database/
|--migrations/
|---2015_01_01_234626_create_categories_table.php
|---2015_02_02_141725_create_problems_table.php
```

Finally:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the foreign key in a different migration file, fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem days ago and the problem was the following:

on use `$table->increments('id');`, it generates a `unsigned` integer with **length 10**. and `$table->integer('user_id')` generate a not `unsigned` integer with **length 11**.

To fix it you might give up the `unsigned` and set all field's table that will be related to the others only as a `auto increment` field, like this:

```
$table->integer('id', true); // true represents the auto increment type
```

And, of course, set the `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`.